# How to create this dispersion effect on a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, effects

Does anyone know how I can create this effect in Illustrator on an already designed circle shape? For example, I have a gold coin I created and I want to apply this kind of like dispersion effect to it. Tried creating a pattern then trimming on top of the shape but it didn't work.

How is this effect created? If you can point me in a direction or even show me a tutorial that would be great. Or even if you could tell me what is the effect called and research it myself. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's just colored shapes. You won't find any filter or effect to do it for you.

Comment: Don't want to find any filter or effect to do it for me. I just can't understand how to create it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pre-canned effect with which I am familiar which does this with this degree of *finesse*; it was most likely simply created.

Here's one workflow to get there, with two minor variations in approach.

**Part one: Colour tiles.**

1. Tile hexagons using **Alt-Drag** for first copy; **Cmd-D** for repeating.
2. Grab hexagon rows using marquee, colour in sequence, using **eyedropper** to grab last, then iterate colour.
3. **Alt-drag** to new artboard, use **eyedropper** to rework colour dispersal to angle.
4. Randomize colours

**Part Two: Two quick approaches to final form.**

1. Apply **clipping mask** of circle, add white hexes where needed, and centre circle.
2. Apply **Object>Path>Split Below Path** to each circle, larger first, then manipulate results as needed.

See attached image.

[image]

Comment: Can I add it over something like this?  https://goo.gl/images/mCRAdX

Comment: Assuming you drew something like that as a *vector-based drawing in illustrator*, then yes, the technique described would indeed still apply in that case.<br/>
<br/>
If it were, as in the image provided, a Photoshop raster-based image, you could something similar, in which you created the vector part as described, then overlaid it on top of your PS image, setting an appropriate transparency mode. If you do that, you might also want to clip a number of versions of the image with hexes...